# Rails Secure Download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, download

I am building an rails app and I want to secure the user's downloads.

The scenario is:
There is an item with a download column of "/some_directories/some_file.zip".

A user buys the file, goes to "My downloads" page and clicks "Download". The download button is checking if the user really bought the file, and if he did it is sending the data of the download column of the item. All is good. Now, the user will see where the download came from (example.com/some_directories/some_file.zip) and just send the URL to his friends. My question is, how can I prevent this situation? How can I let only the customers of the item download this file, no matter what?

Thank you very much

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another popular way of handling this in a scalable way that doesn't tie up your Rails processes is to use Amazon S3 and generate a URL that is only valid for a short period of time (e.g. 3 minutes).

It doesn't rule out the possibility of someone sending the URL to another friend to be accessed immediately, but then again, if they're downloading something they can just send it to their friend later too. The idea here is that it prevents someone from posting the URL on a forum somewhere for people to access for years to come.

[S3 Documentation for time-limited query-string authentication.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html)

Comment: Well that's just what I wanted. Can you please give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: [This article](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads) goes into the implementation details for securing Paperclip-uploaded files. You can surely extract the relevant bits from the S3-integration section if you're not using Paperclip.

Comment: I am using paperclip. One question, can I re-generate an expired link every 10 minutes? I mean, generate an expired link -> When he expires, generate another one -> Over and over again.. Is it possible?

Comment: You generate a unique access url for each download request and redirect the user to it immediately. Follow the article I linked to and it'll explain all of that and give you the code to do it too.

Comment: Hi Corey, thanks for the quick answers. When I try to use their code, I get the following error: UnInitialized Constant AWS in this line:           redirect_to(AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(path, item.download.bucket_name, :expires_in => 10.seconds))

Comment: You have to install the AWS::S3 gem.

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you very much!! Just a quick question: Is the link being re-generated every time it expires?

Comment: No. Read the article, and/or my comment above. "You generate a unique access url for each download request." That is, when a user clicks "Download" your controller gets a temporary access URL and redirects the user to it, immediately. Every time. Always a different URL.

Comment: Yes, that is not a problem but the download link it self will be expired already..

Comment: I mean, the download URL in amazon will be expired after 10 seconds. I want it to re-generate an Amazon link, not a temporary URL in the site.

Comment: I give up. You are missing what is right in front of you. I don't know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue as you. My solution was to store the file in a database via Paperclip and restrict access that way with authlogic and declarative_authorization. Works like a charm!

https://github.com/patshaughnessy/paperclip - version of paperclip that allows database file storage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What do you mean by "store the file in a database"? How can you store a file in the database without uploading it to the server? And when you restrict the access, the user can just see the send_data URL and send it to his friends.